# cram planning algorithm

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Cram-system is a high level A.I. planning executive, so, I am wondering what kind of planning algorithm that Cram-system is using in the latest version ?
Also, I am wondering how cram-system make use of knowrob knowledge base ?
As far as I know, KB may be used for evaluating preconditions of actions in planning system but I still can't find any clue about it. I am desperately looking for how symantic web based planning system works in cram-system.
Which program source codes either in cram-system or knowrob should I read to find out the issues that may address about the above two questions ?
Thanks.

Dongho Song,
Korea Aerospace Univ.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206387/cram-planning-algorithm/) by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you could start by going through the `cram` tutorials which as very well documented at http://www.cram-system.org/doc/beginner/simple_plans

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on 2015-04-06**:
Thank you for your comment.
Actually, I've read through those docs in tutorials and could run the cram tutorial programs mostly without problem. The more we understand on the cram-system, the more curious to know about the details of Cram.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CRAM does not use classical planning methods such as PDDL. It is a high-level executive rather than a planning system, which means that it focuses on the execution of plans rather than their generation. Usually, a CRAM system consists of a library of carefully written plans for common subtasks such as navigation or picking up objects, which are hierarchically composed to higher-level plans.

These plan fragments are 'universal', i.e. they do not specify preconditions that need to be fulfilled by some external procedure, but contain code for checking these preconditions and for making them true. For example, a plan for picking up an object may require the object to be in reach and visible, and contain calls to methods for navigating sufficiently close and for opening surrounding containers before starting the grasping action.

KnowRob is used by the plan fragments for reading parameter values and for taking decisions. As a rule of thumb, all environment-, object- or context-dependent pieces of information are not stored in the plans themselves, but in the knowledge base, and are read by queries during plan execution.

More details on the CRAM language can be found in [1], on the general concepts behind the CRAM/KnowRob ecosystem in [2], and on the interaction between CRAM and KnowRob in [3].

[1] Michael Beetz, Lorenz Mösenlechner, Moritz Tenorth, "CRAM -- A Cognitive Robot Abstract Machine for Everyday Manipulation in Human Environments", In Proceedings of the IEEE/RSJ International Conference on Intelligent Robots and Systems, Taipei, Taiwan, pp. 1012-1017, 2010.

[2] Michael Beetz, Dominik Jain, Lorenz Mösenlechner, Moritz Tenorth, Lars Kunze, Nico Blodow, Dejan Pangercic, "Cognition-Enabled Autonomous Robot Control for the Realization of Home Chore Task Intelligence", In Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 100, no. 8, pp. 2454-2471, 2012.

[3] Moritz Tenorth, Michael Beetz, "KnowRob -- A Knowledge Processing Infrastructure for Cognition-enabled Robots", In International Journal of Robotics Research (IJRR), vol. 32, no. 5, pp. 566 - 590, 2013.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dongho](https://answers.ros.org/users/21383/dongho/) on 2015-04-07**:
I appreciate for your answers very much.
I wish many researchers are interested in the above questions and share the answers from you as well.
We will investigate more on Open-ease, Cram planning, and interacting with Knowrob through "ask" "tell".
Again, thank you very much.
Dongho